# Distributions of a group of i.i.d Gaussians after Gram-Schmidt Orthogonalization

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If I have a collection of i.i.d standard Gaussian random vectors, say $\{\mathbf{x}_i\}_{i=1}^{\lambda}\sim \boldsymbol{\mathcal{N}}(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{I}_n),\lambda < n$, then I orthogonalize them by the Gram-Schmidt process, yielding a group of orthonormal vectors, say $\{\mathbf{y}_i\}_{i=1}^{\lambda}$. Is it possible to derive the probability density of any of $\{\mathbf{y}_i\}_{i=1}^{\lambda}$?

Comment: that is the haar measure on the orthogonal group, but i don't know a better description of it than the one you  just gave.

Comment: I don't understand your question, since if all of the variable are independent then the Gram-Schmidt-Orthogonalization should not change them at all.

Answer (score 0):

write the matrix form of Gram-Schimdt Orthogonalization: $X = Y R$ 
($\mathbf{X}_i$ are the columns of $X$, $\mathbf{Y}_i$ are the columns of $Y$ and $R$ is upper triangular). 
Actually it is a QR factorization: $X = A$, $Y = \hat Q$ and $R$ is $\hat R$ in the following description:

[image: QR factorization 1]

[image: QR factorization 2]

From that description you can compute the $\mathbf{Y}_i$ probability densities...